How to prevent Android Bitmap from being automatically disposed when generated on background thread from Task.Run() in C#?
I am loading "native bitmaps" (Android Bitmap in Android) into a wrapper class in C#:
public class NativeBitmap {
    public Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap;
    public int rawHeight = 0;
    public int rawWidth = 0;
}

I am loading Android Bitmaps into this wrapper class from disk using:
private async Task<NativeBitmap> getNativeBitmapFromDisk(string localPhotoPathAndName) {

    NativeBitmap nativeBitmap = new();

    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(localPhotoPathAndName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {

        nativeBitmap.bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(fs);
        nativeBitmap.rawWidth = nativeBitmap.bitmap.Width;
        nativeBitmap.rawHeight = nativeBitmap.bitmap.Height;   
    }
    return nativeBitmap;

}

I can now run this in two ways: (1) on main thread or (2) on background thread. Background threading is faster and desirable, but if I run this as:
//main thread method (works):
photoNativeBitmap[0] = await getNativeBitmapFromDisk(localPhotoPathAndName); //main threaded, works

//background thread method (DOES NOT RELIABLY WORK):
//photoNativeBitmap[0] = await Task.Run(() => getNativeBitmapFromDisk(localPhotoPathAndName)); 

try {
    Debug.WriteLine("GOT ANDROID PHOTO, WIDTH: " + photoNativeBitmap[0].bitmap.Width);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION ON TASK RUN: " + e.Message);
}

Using the background thread Task.Run method often lands me into the exception which states for e.Message:
Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Android.Graphics.Bitmap'

So when I am using this method via Task.Run as described above, the Android Bitmap is being sometimes disposed by the operating system before it is returned back to the main thread.
Is this expected behavior? Or possibly some type of C#/.NET bug? I would like to use the loading via Task.Run to try to perform the Bitmap loading off the main thread but not if the Bitmap will be garbage collected in the process.
Thanks for any thoughts or ideas.

Is there a special reason not to use DecodeStreamAsync method?

I am not sure if that will also still give this issue or not. I could try switching to that to see if it helps performance. I am not clear, but I think it will still be using more main thread CPU consumption for this than I need. If I am intentionally background threading the entire load function, which is what I want (ie. Task.Run), I don't think that will help improve the issue. I do not need the Bitmap load to happen on the main thread at all, except for this Bitmap disposal issue I can't make sense of. Thanks for any further thoughts.

You should also give DecodeFileAsync a try. The Bitmap class smells like being tight coupled to the thread it was created in
